# How to also list duplicates values within IN?

Tags: mysql

I have a query where the elements I want to show come from a *big list of elements* where you can have the same element several times and I need to show all the elements from that list, even those elements that are repeated.

Table is called **features** and its fields are *id*, *name*, *type*.

In this example the list of elements is **(1, 15, 15, 15, 23, 46)** where 15 is repeated three times.

My initial query (it does not work):

`SELECT f.* FROM features f WHERE f.id IN (1, 15, 15, 15, 23, 46)`

When I run the query it only shows me elements 1,15,23, 46 and I'd love to see a query listing you all those 6 elements. Is that possible? How?

EDIT: This data (features) is used to create cards for a deck of cards. The cards are chosen by the user and they can choose the same card several times.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the overall development problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Are you sure the row data for features table has duplicated rows with id `15`? Can you post your data by querying `SELECT * FROM features` as from your code if there's no `distinct` used it should return all rows with id `15` and not just 1

Comment: The list must be converted to the rowset.

Comment: This data is used to create cards for a deck of cards. The cards are chosen by the user and they can choose the same card several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list must be a rowset in FROM, not a list in WHERE:

```sql
SELECT f.* 
FROM features f 
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL
      SELECT 15 UNION ALL
      SELECT 15 UNION ALL
      SELECT 15 UNION ALL
      SELECT 23 UNION ALL
      SELECT 46) criteria USING (id)
```

Comment: Wisely done, I am worried about performance, but.

Comment: @nanmaniac *I am worried about performance* Must be the same.